# How to query for _id that's not of type ObjectId

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

(I'm new to mongo)

**How do I query for an _id that's not of type ObjectId?**

I mongorestore'd a mongodump and can't get any results based on the id field. I noticed after a while that the records in the collection didn't adhere to the ObjectID type.

`"_id": "7409a2ab-322e-40f3-b991-c3ebeda78f61",`

If I change the id to `id:"5c47422231caf0939f3d7cc7"` then my query will work correctly since that matches the ObjectID type.

I just keep getting `CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "f7757753-c450-42f9-b0f9-9a617628fcfa" at path "_id" for model "mydb"`

I've tried querying `mydb.findById({ _id: 'f7757753-c450-42f9-b0f9-9a617628fcfa' })` and `mydb.findOne({ _id: 'f7757753-c450-42f9-b0f9-9a617628fcfa' }` and `mydb.findOne({ _id: 'f7757753-c450-42f9-b0f9-9a617628fcfa' }`

also tried incorporating ObjectId casting into my queries like so: `{ _id: ObjectId("f7757753-c450-42f9-b0f9-9a617628fcfa") }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your model you say you have Object id as the data type of ID right? So it's normal to scream the cast error when you use this

> 7409a2ab-322e-40f3-b991-c3ebeda78f61

as the _id.. So you need to change your model( schema actually) in a way that your type if the id will be a string not a object id

```
{
_id : String,
blah,
blah,
blah,
}
```

Comment: Ahhh, in my model I had id: String instead of _id: String. I was missing the underscore. Thanks!